# Is intravenous Haldol being phased out for something else?

Tags: antipsychotic

Haldol has very high risk of extra pyramidal side effects and can result in even temporary kidney failure in extreme cases.

With even these serious side effects in comparison to modern medications it is regarded as [essential medication](https://apps.who.int/iris/rest/bitstreams/1145259/) and Haldol is considered a very [old drug](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloperidol#History).

Is Haldol being phased out for something else? Why not?  I should add prescriptions for haldol seem to be increasing by year not decreasing although some would argue [haldol presciptions are minimal](https://clincalc.com/DrugStats/Drugs/Haloperidol).

Doing a little more research I have established Haldol is being administered intravenously and the only other antipsychotic I have found to do this is [Ziprasidone](https://pubs.asahq.org/anesthesiology/article/101/3/794/9182/Intravenous-Ziprasidone-for-Treatment-of-Delirium#1089162).

Comment: Many essential medications have serious side effects. How do you define a "bad" drug?

Comment: @CareyGregory https://www.crossroadshospice.com/hospice-resources/education-for-families/when-is-haldol-the-right-choice/ I assume it is from the long term extra pyramidal side effects and the fact it is still rising in presciptions(instead of being used intravenously.

Comment: I don't understand your response. You ask if haldol is a "bad" drug so I'm asking how you define "bad."

Comment: I have edited the title to focus on being phased out if there is a newer drug.

Comment: Thanks, much better.